# Issues using iText7 License Library

Tags: .net-core, itext, itext7

I recently downloaded the trial license file from itext.

I load the licensefile like this:

```
        LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile("itextkey.xml");
```

and here is my `csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="itext7" Version="7.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="itext7.licensekey" Version="3.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="itext7.pdfhtml" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

With this configuration all is well.

However, if I switch to `netcoreapp1.1`, the code breaks with the following error:

```
iText.License.LicenseKeyException: Signature was corrupted.
   at iText.License.Validators.LicenseKey7Validator.CheckLicenseeSignature(String signatureBuildString, String licenseeSignature)
   at iText.License.Validators.LicenseKey7Validator.LoadLicense(XmlElement licenseKeyRoot)
   at iText.License.LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFileInternal(Stream licenseIs)
   at iText.License.LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile(String pathToLicFile)
```

How can I get this to work on `1.1`?

Answer (score 1):

The error is essentially telling you "The (decrypted) hash value of the file does not match the hash value I was expecting".

From the [iText website](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/license-key-frequently-asked-questions/common-error-messages):

> This can mean a few things:
>
> - The license key file was corrupted during the download. Try
>     downloading it again and loading the newly downloaded file. If the
>     issue still persists, contact us so that we can resolve this issue.
> - You changed the contents of your license key. Please revert to the
>     original state of the license key. If you want to change the content
>     of the key, please contact our sales department.

Comment: I've read that. The fact that it works on 2.2 but not 1.1 tells me neither of these is the case

Comment: I would suggest getting in touch with your local sales representative. If you have a trial license, you are obviously thinking about potentially buying iText. I'm sure they'd be happy to help a potential customer.

Comment: I thought so as well, but they haven't been very responsive at all.

Comment: To which email address did you send it? If it was someone from the Belgium office, then we can get this solved in less than 30 seconds, I'll just get up from my chair and go to the sales people down the hall. I mean, the responsiveness issue will be solved, the actual license key issue might take some research.

Comment: Okay I see from your Stack Overflow profile that you are located in Brooklyn, NY, so you probably contacted our US office. I'll send them a message on Slack.

Comment: Message sent! And now we wait. :)

Comment: A ticket was created on our support board 2 days ago (16/11/2018 20:49) and hasn't been replied to because, well, it was a weekend, and our US support team has only just started their working day. If you didn't get a reply by the end of this business day, please contact sales.isc@itextpdf.com again.

Comment: One of our developers replied to your sales contact at 17:53 CET (I believe that's 11:53 in your time zone?) requesting for more information. Was that request relayed to you?

Comment: Someone attempted replying to me. She said she tried emailing me a screenshot of the correct license key I should be using, but gmail is rejecting the file.